# Unable to understand non-blocking calls in Redux-Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to understand [Non-blocking calls](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls.html) section of `redux-saga` documentation and stuck with the below code

```js
import { fork, call, take, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...'

function* authorize(user, password) {
  try {
    const token = yield call(Api.authorize, user, password)
    yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', token})
    yield call(Api.storeItem, {token})
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', error})
  }
}

function* loginFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const {user, password} = yield take('LOGIN_REQUEST')
    yield fork(authorize, user, password)
    yield take(['LOGOUT', 'LOGIN_ERROR'])
    yield call(Api.clearItem, 'token')
  }
}
```

The explanation says

> If the authorize fails before the user logs out, it will dispatch a LOGIN_ERROR action, then terminate. So loginFlow will take the LOGIN_ERROR before the LOGOUT then it will enter in a another while iteration and will wait for the next LOGIN_REQUEST action.

I can't really understand the statement *So loginFlow will take the LOGIN_ERROR before the LOGOUT then it will enter in a another while iteration and will wait for the next LOGIN_REQUEST action.*

Can anyone explain the relation between `yield put({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', error})` and `yield take(['LOGOUT', 'LOGIN_ERROR'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield put({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', error})` - dispatches action of type `LOGIN_ERROR`.

`yield take(['LOGOUT', 'LOGIN_ERROR'])` suspends generator function (`loginFlow`) execution until action of type `LOGOUT` or `LOGIN_ERROR` is dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

To simply explain:

- `yield put({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR',error})` = dispatch action indicating that there is a LOGIN_ERROR.
- `yield take(['LOGOUT', 'LOGIN_ERROR'])` = wait until there is an either LOGOUT or LOGIN_ERROR action to be dispatched and only continue executing the next line which is `yield call(Api.clearItem, 'token')` if there is a LOGOUT or LOGIN_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

**NON-BLOCKING**
is a Synchronous flow, which means that the Saga disobey the block of codes and simultaneously read the lines within the parent block, the reason why it was called `Non-Blocking`

**BLOCKING**
call means that the Saga yielded an Effect and await the previous block before it continuous for the next block execution and basically it was called `Blocking`

To your case, you just misunderstood the documentation of redux-saga but it was just about like [this](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/Glossary/#blockingnon-blocking-call)

```
import {call, cancel, join, take, put} from "redux-saga/effects"

function* saga() {
  yield take(ACTION)              // Blocking: will wait for the action
  yield call(ApiFn, ...args)      // Blocking: will wait for ApiFn (If ApiFn returns a Promise)
  yield call(otherSaga, ...args)  // Blocking: will wait for otherSaga to terminate

  yield put(...)                   // Non-Blocking: will dispatch within internal scheduler

  const task = yield fork(otherSaga, ...args)  // Non-blocking: will not wait for otherSaga
  yield cancel(task)                           // Non-blocking: will resume immediately
  // or
  yield join(task)                              // Blocking: will wait for the task to terminate
}
```

For more info just read  about the documentation itself of [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls/#first-try)